# Accept collection of object from View and store it using EF MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two objects of **Student** and **Supervisor** with Many-to-Many relationship.

I have created one junction class manually, since I need to store a property called TagMainOrCo (Indicating the supervisor is Main / Co).

One Student can only have 2 supervisors and One supervisors can have unlimited students under their supervision.

Here is my code snippet:

**Student:**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string MatricNo { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public virtual IList<SupervisorStudents> Supervisors { get; set; }
}
```

**Supervisor:**

```
public class Supervisor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string StaffNumber { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public virtual ICollection<SupervisorStudents> Students { get; set; }
}
```

**Junction Table (SupervisorStudents):**

```
public class SupervisorStudents
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int SupervisorId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string TagMainOrCo { get; set; }

    public virtual Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

So,  what I wanted to do in my View for Student creation is;

1. Displaying **TWO(2) DROPDOWN LIST** for selection of **Main** and
   **Co-supervisor**.
2. The dropdown list should contain the Supervisor List. As I need to
   select the supervisor I want to assign as Main/Co.
3. This view should be able to take the two supervisor details and
   store it inside the database.

So far I am using HtmlHelpers to pass the data. As for the StudentController, to save the student data:

```
        public ActionResult Save(Student student)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var viewModel = new StudentRegistrationViewModel
                    {
                        Student = student,
                        Courses = _context.Courses.ToList(),
                        Faculties = _context.Faculties.ToList(),
                        Semesters = _context.Semesters.ToList(),
                        SupervisorStudentses = _context.StudentSupervisors.ToList()
                    };

                    return View("StudentRegistrationForm", viewModel);
                }

                // If new students
                if (student.Id == 0)
                {
                    _context.Students.Add(student);
                }
               // Other Logics
             }
```

Is there anyway to achieve this without using jQuery or AJAX? Any kind of feedback is really appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990228/mvc-4-passing-a-list-from-a-view-to-a-controller

Comment: Yes. I've already checked that out. Thank you very much for the suggestion! =)